# flex-элементы: заставить их смещаться по три на больших экранах

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox, width

Проблема со смещением флекс-элементов. Никак не могу **заставить их смещаться по три на больших экранах**. Перепробовала все, что возможно: и `flex-basis`, и `max-width`, и тег `break`.

Не получается никак. Смещаются по одному. Уже несколько дней с этим воюю. Не сделать, хоть убей.

Нужно, чтобы на разрешениях от `1505` до `2194`: 4-й, 5-й и 6-й флекс-элементы были на второй строке.

По три элемента оборачивать в отдельный `div`, думаю, не вариант, ибо на меньших разрешениях эта группировка будет мешать размещению по 2 эл-та в строку.

Подскажите, как победить?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-self: center;
}

.choice {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url(Plan.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-content-between {
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  inherit: none;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.line-break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 1488) {
  .container {
    inherit: none;
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 1200 px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100) {
  .container {
    inherit: none;
    width: 95%;
  }
  nav {
    align-content: center;
  }
  .wrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1487) {
  break {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1488) {
  .container {
    width: 60%;
    inherit: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/database.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Последнее обновление</a></h3><br />
        <img src='Today-final.jpg' alt='Все квартиры за сегодня' />
        <figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/area.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3 class="select"><a href=''>По районам СПб</a></h3><br />
        <img src='Metro-distr-final.jpg' alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'>
        <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам и метро</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/sut.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h3><br />
        <img src='Sutochno-final.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'>
        <figcaption>
          Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>

    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/database.html';">
      <break></break>
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Однокомнатные квартиры</a></h3><br />
        <img src='1KKV-final.jpg' alt='Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб' />
        <figcaption>Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/area.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Двухкомнатные квартиры</a></h3><br />
        <img src='2KKV-final.jpg' alt='Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб'>
        <figcaption>Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб
        </figcaption>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.baseflat.ru/sut.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Трехкомнатные квартиры и более</a></h3><br />
        <img src='3KKV-final.jpg' alt='Снять трех-, четырехкомнатную квартиру в СПб'>
        <figcaption>
          Снять трехкомнатную, четырехкомнатную ...</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </nav>
</div>
```

На всех остальных разрешения всё работает, как надо. А с большими экранами я сломала остатки мозга окончательно. В стилях уже все методы вперемешку.

Answer (score 0):

Запаритесь с этими смещениями.
Предлагаю простой выход:

1) После каждого блока добавляете какой-нибудь элемент HTML, например `<em>`:

```
<nav class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
  <section class="choice"> ... </section>
  <em></em>
  <section class="choice"> ... </section>
  <em></em>
  <section class="choice"> ... </section>
  <em></em>
</nav>
```

2) у этого элемента по умолчанию ставите стиль:

```
.choice + em {display:none;}
```

3) с помощью media queries для нужных разрешений заставляете этот элемент разрывать сплошной поток section-ов после каждого третьего:

```
.choice:nth-of-type(3n) + em {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

4) на меньших разрешениях, соответственно, делаете разрыв после каждого второго.

UPD:
Если есть возможность и право сделать ширину `<nav>` меньше ширины экрана или  обернуть section-ы в еще один `<div>`, то задача упрощается до безобразия: этот самый `<nav>` или `<div>` задать такой ширины, чтобы больше трех section-ов в ряд не помещалось при требуемых разрешениях.